# D3 and Select not properly adjusting Html layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, d3.js

I'm doing my best working with D3 in order to align my HTML layout, but I'm not able to align my charts the way I want it.

What I need to obtain is:

```
              BAR CHART

1st PIE CHART, 2nd PIE CHART, FIELDSET
```

Therefore I need to exchange the position of the second Pie Chart with the "Options" `fieldset`.

What I've been trying until now is:

```
var svg = d3.select("#divs").append("div").attr("id","svg-cont")
                .style("margin-top", 50)//.style("margin-left", 405)
                .append("svg").attr("width", 210).attr("height", 200);

      svg.append("g").attr("id","salesDonut");

      var data = [10,20,30,40,50,60];
      var data1 = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];

      if(d3.select('#opt-fieldset').empty()){
          var fieldset = d3.select("#svg-cont").append("fieldset").attr("id","opt-fieldset").style("float","left").style("width",150)
                        .html('<legend>Options</legend>\
                          <d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\
                          <select id="rotation" style="position: right;">\
                          </select>  &nbsp; \
                          <br><d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d>\
                          <select id="inclination" style="position: right;">\
                          </select>'); 

            var rotate = d3.select("#rotation");
                rotate.selectAll("option").data(data).enter().append("option")
                        .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
                        .text(function (d) { return d; });

            var inclinate = d3.select("#inclination");
                inclinate.selectAll("option").data(data1).enter().append("option")
                        .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
                        .text(function (d) { return d; });
      }else{
        console.log("Godspeed");
      }

      Donut3D.draw("salesDonut", getData(data3D),
          marginLeft, marginTop, pieWidth, inclination, pieThickness, pieHole);
```

This is the complete code and result in Plucker -> [(Click on any bar in order to display the 2 pie charts and the fieldset)](http://plnkr.co/edit/QetXyW2RsPujwEIymcDA?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you could align your fieldset to the right instead of the left. IMHO your HTML structure is a bit messy at the moment because the three elements you want to align at the bottom are appended to different parent divs. Styling it ends up being a little hacky. I would suggest the following:

Put both piecharts and fieldset inside the same div container and then style them through CSS.

```
// Since you append the first piechart to #div1, put the second one there as well.
var svg = d3.select("#div1").append("div").attr("id","svg-cont")
                .style("margin-top", 50)//.style("margin-left", 405)
                .append("svg").attr("width", 210).attr("height", 200);

// Append the fieldset also to #div1 which has the other two pie charts
var fieldset = d3.select("#div1")
                 // I've added here another div to wrap the fieldset
                 .append('div')
                 .append("fieldset")
                 // remove the float: left
                 .attr("id","opt-fieldset").style("width",150)
                 .html('<legend>Options</legend>\
                          <d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\
                          <select id="rotation" style="position: right;">\
                          </select>  &nbsp; \
                          <br><d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d>\
                          <select id="inclination" style="position: right;">\
                          </select>'); 

// In your HTML, remove the float:left from the #div1
<div id="div1"></div>

// Lastly, add the following to your styles to align these 3 elements
#div1 > div {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FTmHHBM3vaiIVWQdPIEU?p=preview) forked from yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the css for fieldset style `.style("float","right")`

Something like this:

```
var fieldset = d3.select("#svg-cont").append("fieldset").attr("id","opt-fieldset").style("float","right").style("width",150)
                            .html('<legend>Options</legend>\
                              <d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\
                              <select id="rotation" style="position: right;">\
                              </select>  &nbsp; \
                              <br><d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d>\
                              <select id="inclination" style="position: right;">\
                              </select>');
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WPOzCTKFIuYJdN6CA4tX?p=preview)

Hope this helps!